# Number Pie Chart

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, number-sequence

What should be the missing number?

[image]

Comment: For the number theorists out there, I'd say this puzzle is rather (ROT13) anepvffvfgvp :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is

> $13139$

Because,

> Power $4$ the digits. Summing them will get you to the next number.
>
>  $4338$ -> $4^4 + 3^4 + 3^4 + 8^4$ -> $4514$.
>  $4514$ -> $4^4 + 5^4 + 1^4 + 4^4$ -> $1138$.
>  ...

And yes,

> It makes a cycle, :)
>
>  There is a nice video too about this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_DpzAvb3Vk4 (by Numberphille).

Comment: Very nice answer, and thanks for that referenced video!